# Using Javascript and for loop function to render 2 times multiplication string

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multiplication

So this is what I have so far, I know I'm on the right track but I can't figure out to create a var for totting up the results and integrating that into my code...I understand that the var created for the multiplication should go after the last *"+"* in my *"for"* line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p></p>

<button onclick="loop()">Click here</button>

<p id="forLoop"></p>

<script>
    function loop() {
        var total = "";
        var x;
        for (x = 1; x < 13; x++) total += "2 x " + x + " = " + "<br>";

        document.getElementById("forLoop").innerHTML = total;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need another var. You can just use `x*2`. JavaScript is smart enough to evaluate the result and add it to the string as you would expect.

```
"2 × " + x + " = " + x*2 + "<br />"
```

Few notes:

- To denote "times" (like: "a times b"), HTML has the `&times;` entity which renders like so: ×
- It's considered bad practice to use `<br>` like this in production. Generate a table or a list, and add those as elements.
- You should avoid `.innerHTML` until you are aware of the risks of using it.

Comment: `&times;` Nice didn't know that :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for that, and the extra hints that you took the time to add...much appreciated!